# OpenShift domain status failing

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

So I created an account at open shift, created an app, and installed the command line tool.  when I do the command rhc domain status it fails:

```
Loaded suite /usr/bin/rhc-chk
Started
.E
===============================================================================
Error: test_connectivity(Test1_Connectivity)
  ArgumentError: too few arguments
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:204:in `sprintf'
     201:   message = sprintf(get_message(:errors,name),*(args.shift || ''))
     202:   solution = get_message(:solutions,name)
     203:   if solution
  => 204:     message << "\n" << sprintf(solution,*(args.shift || ''))
     205:   end
     206:   message
     207: end
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:204:in `error_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:270:in `test_connectivity'
===============================================================================
F
===============================================================================
Failure:
  You need to be able to connect to the server in order to test authentication.
  <false> is not true.
test_authentication(Test2_Authentication)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:280:in `test_authentication'
     277:   # Checking Authentication
     278:   #
     279:   def test_authentication
  => 280:     assert $connectivity, error_for(:cant_connect)
     281: 
     282:     data = {'rhlogin' => $rhlogin}
     283:     response = fetch_url_json("/broker/userinfo", data)
===============================================================================
..F
===============================================================================
Failure: You must have an account on the server in order to test: whether you have a valid key loaded in your agent.
test_03_remote_ssh_keys(Test3_SSH)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:317:in `require_login'
     314:   end
     315: 
     316:   def require_login(test)
  => 317:     flunk(error_for(:no_account,test)) if $user_info.nil?
     318:   end
     319: 
     320:   def require_remote_keys(test)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:321:in `require_remote_keys'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:376:in `test_03_remote_ssh_keys'
===============================================================================
F
===============================================================================
Failure: You must have an account on the server in order to test: connecting to your applications.
test_04_ssh_connect(Test3_SSH)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:317:in `require_login'
     314:   end
     315: 
     316:   def require_login(test)
  => 317:     flunk(error_for(:no_account,test)) if $user_info.nil?
     318:   end
     319: 
     320:   def require_remote_keys(test)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rhc-0.94.8/bin/rhc-chk:383:in `test_04_ssh_connect'
===============================================================================


Finished in 2.403595 seconds.

7 tests, 8 assertions, 3 failures, 1 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
42.8571% passed
```

Not really understanding why it's not able to connect. I was able to use: rhc domain show, with no problems.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=836483) that should get fixed in the upcoming release. Even though you see this error it shouldn't affect any other behaviour.

Comment: This has now been resolved - the check previously handled by 'roc domain status' is now automatic when you run 'rhc setup'